# Thread communication in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, message, communication

Could someone explain to me how to manage thread communication in swift3 iOS? I did some research and I found the gcd that manage threads but I need some thing else, I need to notify (send a message or something) thread x that thread y is done or in general to notify the state of that thread, is there any equivalent of thread communication like in java?(notify(), notifyAll(), wait()) but in iOS?
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use GCD, you could take a look at multithreading features in conjunction with the `NSThread` class, like [NSCondition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscondition), or more general, the
[ThreadSafety guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using GCD also with help of Custom Serial Queue. Please refer here:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/60749/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-1